# Compare multiple columns in two separate csv files and when they match parse for a matching string value

Tags: python, pandas, csv, parsing

I need to compare multiple columns in two separate csv files and when the first 4 columns all match between the two csv files, make a new csv file with the matching four columns and then add the 5th and 7th column of the second csv file to it as well as parse the first csv file column 8 to any of the columns in second csv file. if they match then take the subsequent columns value. I know this sounds confusing but below shows what I am trying to do

First.csv

```
Address ID X Y col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 
Bob     16 1 2  x    x    x    ABC  #1
Jon     6  5 7  x    x    x    ABC  #2
Rem     16 4 9  x    x    x    ABC  #3
Bob     16 2 3  x    x    x    ABC  #4
```

Second.csv

```
Address ID X Y col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10 col11 col12 col13 col14 col15 
Bob     16 1 2  x    x    x    def  #    ABC    #5   ghi    #    jkl   # 
Bob     16 1 3  x    x    x    def  #    ABC    #    ghi    #    jkl   #
Jon     6  5 7  x    x    x    def  #    ghi    #    ABC    #6   jkl   #
Jon     6  5 8  x    x    x    def  #    ghi    #    ABC    #    jkl   #
Rem     16 4 9  x    x    x    def  #    ghi    #    jkl    #    ABC   #7
Rem     16 4 8  x    x    x    def  #    ghi    #    jkl    #    ABC   #
Bob     16 2 3  x    x    x    ABC  #8   def    #    ghi    #    jkl   #
Bob     16 2 6  x    x    x    ABC  #    def    #    ghi    #    jkl   #
```

output.csv

```
Address ID X Y 1 2 3   4   5  6
Bob     16 1 2 x x x  ABC #1 #5
Jon     6  5 7 x x x  ABC #2 #6
Rem     16 4 9 x x x  ABC #3 #7
Bob     16 2 3 x x x  ABC #4 #8
```

I have been trying to use conditional statements like:

```
pathFirst = "C:\First.csv"
pathFinal  = "C:\Second.csv"

dataFirst = pd.read_csv(pathFirst)
dataFinal = pd.read_csv(pathFinal)

Output = pd.DataFrame(columns=['status'], index=dataFirst.index)
Output['status'] = (dataFirst['Address'] == dataFinal['address'] & dataFirst['ID'] == dataFinal['ID']).replace([True, False], ['Matching', 'Not Matching'])

Output.to_csv('C:\output.csv')
```

Just to see if there is a line that is actually comparing correctly but seem like there is just a couple. I know I am doing this wrong and I hope this is explained well enough so I really appreciate any help. Thank you.

EDIT:
I only want the first four columns to match. Address, ID, X, Y after that I want to match column 4 string value in First.csv file with the same string value in columns 4,6 8 or 10 in Second.csv. If they match then take the #value from the next column. So if in Second.csv row 1 column 6 matches the string from the First.csv file then I want Second.csv row 1 column 7s #value.

Comment: how the column `5` matches? both csv files have different values for column `5`

Comment: I only want the first four columns to match. Address, ID, X, Y after that I want to match column 4 sting value in csv file 1 with the same string value in columns 4,6 8 or 10 in csv file 2. If they match then take the #value from the next column. So if row 1 column 6 matches the string from the first csv file then I want row 1 column 7s #value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('first.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('second.csv')

res = df1.merge(df2.iloc[:, :4], on=['Address', 'ID', 'X', 'Y'])

val = [np.where(df2[str(n)].isin(df1['4']), df2[str(n + 1)], np.nan) for n in range(4, 11, 2)]

res['6'] = pd.DataFrame(val).replace('#', np.nan).T.dropna(how='all').bfill(axis=1)[0].to_list()

print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
  Address  ID  X  Y  1  2  3    4   5   6
0     Bob  16  1  2  x  x  x  ABC  #1  #5
1     Jon   6  5  7  x  x  x  ABC  #2  #6
2     Rem  16  4  9  x  x  x  ABC  #3  #7
3     Bob  16  2  3  x  x  x  ABC  #4  #8
```

Comment: Hey deadshot, I tried this and ran into a couple of error. The first was np. I am assuming this is the import numpy as np. once I added that i cam getting a KeyError('4') which I think is  apart of this isin(df1['4'].

Comment: What is the data type of your columns. If it is not string remove quotes it will work

Comment: the name of the column in the csv file is a string as well as the data in all the rows are string values as well

Comment: can you share the result of `print(df.columns)`

Comment: I have to change the column names for this post but using 'print(res.columns)' it gave me: Index(['Address', 'ID', 'X', 'Y', 'String1', 'string2', 'string3','string4',
       'Unnamed: 8'],
      dtype='object') where all the rows in string4 are what I want to use as the compare.

Comment: you should change column names according to your data. or you can update your post with the data you are working i will update the answer